# Facebook Mobile App Install Ads: "0 people play this"

Tags: facebook, mobile, ads

I'm using the new Mobile App Install Ads in my app and installs get count as expected. 
However, I still see the message "0 people play this" in the ad. So far I only make the following call when my app get activated:

```
[FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID].
```

Do I have to insert some other call to Facebook to get this to work?

Comment: How many users are actually reported as using your app in the app insights? this should be where that number comes from, it lags about 48 hours behind realtime

Comment: So far I only see data on the Mobile App Install graph - that reflect app installs - those numbers seem correct. I run the ad since three days now. Maybe the number in the ad preview is not showing the correct number of players. The link "Install Now" also never worked for me.

Comment: Until the regular app insights have updated the MAU for the app, the old (in this case 0?) MAU will be shown in the auth dialog and ads

Comment: Thanks @Igy, will see what the next days will bring. I also noticed that on the app dashboard, both "Daily New Users" and "Daily Active Users" are zero - so far.

Comment: Want to update this question: If your app doesn't have Facebook Connect build in, it will not count and you always see "0 people play this". As far as I could see, Facebook did not display this text anymore if your app does not have Facebook Connect setup.